# integer square root of an integer, why does this work?

Tags: assembly, square-root

Good morning everyone, today I have been shown a clever way to evaluate the integer square root of an integer. Although it is indeed working I fail to understand why it works.
Here' s the code:

```
mov output, 0
mov eax, input
mov ebx, 1
loop:
sub eax, ebx 
cmp eax, 0   
jl end      
inc output
add ebx, 2
jmp loop
end:
```

Now please pay attention to my question, I know how this works: it decreases the input by uneven numbers (1,3,5,7...), if the input is still >=0 it increases the output by 1 and repeats the process, else output is the integer square root of input. What I don' t know is the reason this algorithm works, I' m asking if anyone knows it.

Comment: Notice 1 = 1, 1 + 3 = 4, 1 + 3 + 5 = 9... In general sum of the first n odd numbers is n^2. This is one of the very common series http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4348/sum-of-odd-numbers-results-in-a-square-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the sum of for i = 1 to n of (2 i - 1), reverse the numbers and add:

```
      1 +    3 +    5 +    7 + ... + 2n-3 + 2n-1
+  2n-1 + 2n-3 + 2n-5 + 2n-7 + ... +    3 +    1
   ----------------------------------------------
     2n +   2n +   2n +   2n + ... +   2n +   2n
```

= 2n^2 but since the sum was added twice divide by 2 so

The sum of for i = 1 to n of (2 i - 1) = n^2.